# "Chemmacros" not work in Springer LaTeX template with error "\state" already defined

Tags: templates, springer

In Springer LaTeX [template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support). When add `\usepackage{chemmacros}` will casue the error

> ! LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\state' already defined.
> For immediate help type H .
> ...
> l.5552 ...:nnnnnn} {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} {#6} }
> ?

In the `.cls` file, there is

```
%% Address tagging 
\newcommand{\orgdiv}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\orgname}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\orgaddress}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\street}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\postcode}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\city}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\state}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\country}[1]{#1}%
```

I guess deleting the `\newcommand{\state}[1]{#1}%` will cause other problems in the template. So, how to repair it without needing to delete the `\newcommand{\state}[1]{#1}%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the preamble you can put

```
\let\springerstate\state 
\let\state\relax 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
```

That would work and mean `\state` was the `chemmacros` version.

However since the springer address macros don't actually do anything, I suspect that they are used by an external tool to extract the address for their indexing, so if you have an address than needs a `\state` field it is probably best to put it back locally rather than use `\springerstate`

so

```
\let\springerstate\state 
\let\state\relax 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\let\chemstate\state
\let\state\springerstate
```

so `\state` is the address command and `\chemstate` is chemistry (which you could re-set to `\state` after the address if you wished)

Comment: I checked it and found that the Springer uses the `\state` to make address. You way is good!

Comment: @Y.zeng yes it is for the address, but it does not do anything, `\state{New York}` is the same as `New York`  so I suspect they have external tools to search for the address and search for State and the other fields, so while `New York` or `\springerstate{New York}` would work for you or latex, it may not work for their actual production process. But that only matters if you have a USA or similar address that has a `\state` line.